# How can I access pen pressure data on windows using rust?

Tags: windows, rust, com, stylus-pen, windows-rs

I need to access the pen pressure of windows stylus inputs similar to the libinput `Tablet(Axis(_))`-Event like I implemented [here](https://github.com/Bloeckchengrafik/noted/blob/3b7b355102dd3b5013637e9bd3e1b03de9266060/src/input/libinput_input_device.rs).

Since using libinput is a linux-specific library and doesn't work on windows, I tried using the RealTimeStylus-API using the `windows-rs`-crate.

After instanceating the com object with `CoCreateInstance(&RealTimeStylus, None, CLSCTX_ALL)`, I ran into two issues:

1. If I try to use the `SetHWND`-Method to bind the window to the object, it needs a `::windows_core::IntoParam<super::super::Foundation::HANDLE_PTR>`, not a HWND. While compiling, I get the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `HWND: CanInto<HANDLE_PTR>` is not satisfied                                                                                               
    --> src\input\win_input_device.rs:43:40
     |
43   |             i_real_time_stylus.SetHWND(hwnd).unwrap();
     |                                ------- ^^^^ the trait `CanInto<HANDLE_PTR>` is not implemented for `HWND`
     |                                |
     |                                required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `CanInto<T>`:
               <Battery as CanInto<IUnknown>>
               <Battery as CanInto<IInspectable>>
               <windows::core::imp::IAgileObject as CanInto<IUnknown>>
               <IAgileReference as CanInto<IUnknown>>
               <BatteryReport as CanInto<IUnknown>>
               <BatteryReport as CanInto<IInspectable>>
               <windows::core::imp::IErrorInfo as CanInto<IUnknown>>
               <ILowLevelDevicesAggregateProvider as CanInto<IUnknown>>
             and 452 others
     = note: required for `HWND` to implement `IntoParam<HANDLE_PTR, CopyType>`
note: required by a bound in `IRealTimeStylus::SetHWND`
    --> C:\Users\***\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\windows-0.51.1\src\Windows\Win32\UI\TabletPC\mod.rs:7079:13
     |
7077 |     pub unsafe fn SetHWND<P0>(&self, hwnd: P0) -> ::windows_core::Result<()>
     |                   ------- required by a bound in this associated function
7078 |     where
7079 |         P0: ::windows_core::IntoParam<super::super::Foundation::HANDLE_PTR>,
     |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `IRealTimeStylus::SetHWND`
```

Trying to convert between the two types manually (`i_real_time_stylus.SetHWND(HANDLE_PTR(hwnd.0 as _)).unwrap();`) fails: The program just hangs indefinetly on the SetHWND Method.

2. To access events, I'd need to register an input plugin using [AddStylusSyncPlugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/rtscom/nf-rtscom-irealtimestylus-addstylussyncplugin) (or the async equivalent), but the required interface is only provided as a struct, not a trait to implement.

Is there an easier way to get the current pen pressure? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: After trying to build a minimal reproducible example, I noticed that the first issue was just caused by the way I got to the hwnd object:

```rust
let hwnd = HWND(<Win32WindowHandle>.hwnd as isize);
if !unsafe { IsWindow(hwnd).into() } {
    panic!("HWND is not a vaild window");
}
```

It works using `GetActiveWindow`. The second issue is still problematic...

Comment: That's an odd API, but the `windows-rs` bindings necessarily have to follow what the API expects. The explicit conversion code looks correct. If the program hangs, you'll have to provide a [mcve] to understand the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've updated my question accordingly... If you know of another/better api for this, please let me know!

Comment: By *"second issue"*, I assume you are referring to implementing an `IStylusSyncPlugin` COM object. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that's it. I got to the point where I #[implement] but I can't pass it to the AddStylusSyncPlugin because there's a type error telling that the struct is not an IntoParam<IStylusSyncPlugin>

Comment: I'm lost on this one. I managed to have the system call into my `DataInterest()` implementation once, but I cannot reproduce it. I was passing `&Into::<IStylusSyncPlugin>::into(plugin)`, but something about the design doesn't look right. The functionality is implemented in the `IStylusPlugin` interface, but then there are the (marker) interfaces `IStylusSyncPlugin` and `IStylusAsyncPlugin`. I've never seen marker interfaces used in COM, and I wonder whether this is supported by `windows-rs` at all. I'll try to put a [mcve] together and ask [there](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/).